# Kohana 3 under PHP 5.1.6

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I've been experimenting with Kohana 3 for the past few weeks, and up to now I was quite impressed. I just upload my project to the live server, and I realized I needed one of the lastest version of PHP (5.3) and that I'm stuck with 5.1.6, with this said server.

Now, this may not be the cause of the problem, but every PHP variable found in the views aren't parsed correctly. For example, if I output a link

```
echo Html::anchor('form/registration', 'I Accept,<br />Enter', array('class' => 'left'));
```

I'll have :

```
<a href="" class="">
```

So I guess I'm missing some functionalities of PHP which they added in the lastest version. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, show another examples of "every PHP variable found in the views aren't parsed correctly". How do you use these vars in a view?

Comment: how can you get anything?? ko3 simply cant run with this php version. very strange

Comment: Yes well it seems it is still retro compatible to some extent. My app is not complex by any means.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. The problem was related to the version of PHP, I did upload the app on another server running PHP 5.3.X, and everything was okay, confirming my doubts.

I did track the bug to a certain function which used PHP's htmlspecialchars (HTML::chars) - anyway, I simply used Kohana 2.3 equivalent function and everything is now fine. Well, I had to deal with some other issue, related to PHP 5.1.6 (why, in the name of the holy mother of god, any hosting solution would still be using this backward version?), but at least I didn't had to rewrite the app under another framework of under an older version of Kohana.